# Can you use constants in action files?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, action, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to define a constant in an action file, but for some reason its not working. Is this even possible?

Here is what my action file looks like:

```
uint8 ROS_CONTROLLED=0
uint8 RANDOM_MOVEMENT=1
# Goal
geometry_msgs/Pose actorPose
string actorName
uint8 actorType # 0 = ros controlled, 1 = random movement
---
# Result
bool spawnedSuccesfully
string errorCode
---
# Feedback
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358873/can-you-use-constants-in-action-files?/) by [prithupareek](https://answers.ros.org/users/55533/prithupareek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2020-08-07**:
In what way does it not work? At first glance it seems correct.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-08-07**:
Well, as you told in the [wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/msg#Constants), you can declare and assign constant in msgs types so I assume that can be done in action msgs too. This is because when catkin generate their bindings it is generating the necessary msgs types for the action.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your help. I was able to figure out the answer. I was trying to publish to the goal topic of the action server using rospub from the command line, but it appears that the constants only compile when publishing to the goal from a c++ or python file. I was able to get it to work from there.

You would have to do something like this:

```
goal.actorType = goal.ROS_CONTROLLED
```

---

Originally posted by [prithupareek](https://answers.ros.org/users/55533/prithupareek/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-07-20**:
Note it is slightly preferrable to use the static form `MyActionGoal::ROS_CONTROLLED`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can:

```
# MyAction.action
# Goal constants
uint8 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = 42
---
# Result constants
uint8 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB = 42
---
# Feedback constants
uint8 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC = 42
```

Build it
To access each one :

```
# my_script.py
from my_robot.msg import MyActionGoal, MyActionFeedback, MyActionResult

print(MyActionGoal.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)
print(MyActionFeedback.CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
print(MyActionResult.BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB)
```

EXTRA tip to check if it's defined:

```
# my_script.py
from my_robot.msg import MyActionGoal, MyActionFeedback, MyActionResult

print(MyActionGoal.__dict__.keys())
print(MyActionFeedback.__dict__.keys())
print(MyActionResult.__dict__.keys())
```

You'll get something like this:

```
['AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'deserialize_numpy', '_type', 'deserialize', '_has_header', '_slot_types', 'serialize', '_full_text',
'__module__', '_md5sum', '_get_types', '__slots__', '__doc__', 'serialize_numpy', '__init__']
['deserialize_numpy', '_type', 'deserialize', '_has_header', '_slot_types', 'serialize', '_full_text', '__module__', '_md5sum', '_get
_types', '__slots__', '__doc__', 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC', 'serialize_numpy', '__init__']
['deserialize_numpy', '_type', 'deserialize', '_has_header', '_slot_types', 'serialize', '_full_text', '__module__', 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBB', '_md5sum', '_get_types', '__slots__', '__doc__', 'serialize_numpy', '__init__']
```

---

Originally posted by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) with karma: 65 on 2020-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1